# Help needed with this problem in algebra.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $t$ be a real number such that $t^2 = at + b$ for some positive integral values of $a$ and $b$, then $t^3$ can never be equal to:

> A. $4t+3$
>
> B. $8t+5$
>
> C. $10t+3$
>
> D. $6t+5$

Comment: Why is this tagged as abstract algebra?

Comment: Why would someone upvote this question?  The asker provided no evidence of effort or any research of the question. Pity is not a reason to upvote.  Nor is "I answered it, so I will upvote the question"

Comment: Why are the answers downvoted?

Comment: When someone answers a low-quality posts, they risk downvotes for having done so, (very many users do this), in part or because providing an answer is rewarding an asker who posts a verbatim problem statement, expecting us to "Do my homework for me!"

Comment: Darn, @kingW3, nice find! I wish I had seen that before I voted to close as off topic (no context/effort)!  Argh, Now I can't use the "dupe hammer!"

Comment: Thank you for the answers and for the criticism, too. I'd rather than you can forgive someone new to this exchange for not following etiquettes she was unaware of. Further, it's not a problem I came across in a homework assignment and it was something I really couldn't comprehend when I asked for help. A math community should be a little less hostile to a new entry. Thank you and sorry to everyone I might have offended. Ciao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$t^3=t(t^2)=t(at+b)=at^2+bt=a(at+b)+bt=(a^2+b)t+ab$$

If $(a,b)=(1,3)$, $(a^2+b)t+ab=4t+3$.

If $(a,b)=(3,1)$, $(a^2+b)t+ab=10t+3$.

If $(a,b)=(1,5)$, $(a^2+b)t+ab=6t+5$.

If $(a^2+b)t+ab=8t+5$ then $ab=5$ and hence $(a,b)=(1,5)$ or $(5,1)$. In both cases, $a^2+b\ne8$.

$t^3$ cannot be $8t+5$.

Answer (score 0):

$$t^2=at+b \tag 1$$

$\implies t^3=at^2+bt$

(Multiplying both the sides by $t$)

$\implies t^3=a(at+b)+b=(a^2+b)t+ab$

$\big($from $(1)$ $\big)$

Now you can check the options. For example, I am checking (A)

If $t^3=4t+3 \implies (a^2+b)t+ab=4t+3 $

This is possible if $a=1$ and $b=3$. Option A : rejected.

Can you take it from here?